# What does $\nabla_g$ mean?

Tags: calculus, notation, soft-question

> Let $g$ be an affine map as in the previous point ($g(x)=Ax+b$, for $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m, n}$, $b \in \mathbb{R}^m$), let $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$, and let $h(x)=f(g(x))$. Show that
> $$\nabla_{x}h(x)=A^T\nabla_{g}f(g(x))$$

Before even solving the problem, I'm not sure what $\nabla_g$ means. Can you tell me what this symbol means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It must be the gradient operator. Here $f=f(y)$, where $y\in \mathbb R^m$, and then $y=g(x)$. That $\nabla_g$ must be a (unfortunate) choice of notation for $\nabla f(y)=(\partial_{y_1} f, \ldots, \partial_{y_m} f)$.

Comment: Oh so $\nabla_g$ is the gradient operator respect to each $y_1, ...y_m$ for $y=g(x)$, is that what you mean? I think I get it.

Comment: I really think so.